# Learning Inverse Galois Theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, soft-question, galois-theory

Can someone give me a roadmap for learning Inverse Galois theory?

I am a PhD student in the representation theory of finite groups. I studied Galois theory when I was an undergraduate student. The Inverse Galois Problem is one of my favourite problems in mathematics. I want to read the book Inverse Galois Theory. (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-55420-3)

Could you give me some advice? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't already know about it, you might take a look at [Groups as Galois Groups: An Introduction](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511471117), by Helmut Volklein.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to suggest that a good place to start is with John Thompson's work on the subject. He initiated the modern approach using the notion of "rigid" tuples of conjugacy classes.

Comment: See for example Journal of Algebra, 89 (2) (1984), 437–499. Disclaimer: He was my PhD advisor.